# SQL - Запрос. Для каждого жанра найти три книги, количество доступных экземпляров которых максимально

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите решить:
Для каждого жанра найти три книги, количество доступных экземпляров которых максимально. Если у четвертой и далее книг количество экземпляров такое же, как у третьей, то вывести их всех. Вывести название жанра, название книги, доступное количество экземпляров. Информация должна быть отсортирована по названию жанра в алфавитном порядке, затем по убыванию количества доступных книг и, наконец, по названию книг в алфавитном порядке.

Пояснение
В табличном выражении для каждого жанра пронумеруйте книги с помощью оконной функции RANK().
В основном запросе, отберите все книги, ранг которых меньше или равен 3.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал составить такой запрос:

```
select genre_name, title, available_numbers from
(
select genre_name, title, available_numbers, rank() over tab as r
from book
join genre using(genre_id)

window  tab as (
PARTITION BY genre_name --, available_numbers 
order by genre_name, available_numbers desc, title 
ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING )
) a
where r <= 3
```

Comment: что-то мне посказывает, что rows between тут не к месту

Comment: пока что не могу придумать что-то новое

Comment: вам предложено написать цте, в котором будут пронумерованы книги. Вот вы сначала их просто пронумеруйте. окна должны быть сгруппированы по жанру а внутри отсортированы по количеству.

Comment: *Пояснение В табличном выражении для каждого жанра пронумеруйте книги с помощью оконной функции RANK(). В основном запросе, отберите все книги, ранг которых меньше или равен 3.* Дурь. Одним RANK() тут не обойдёшься. Более того, в некоторых вариантах решения (включая оптимальное) он вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data AS (
SELECT genre_name, title, available_numbers, rank() OVER w AS 'rank'
FROM book 
    INNER JOIN genre USING (genre_id)
WINDOW w AS (
        PARTITION BY genre_name
        ORDER BY available_numbers DESC) 
)

SELECT genre_name, title, available_numbers
FROM data
WHERE data.rank <= 3
ORDER BY genre_name, available_numbers DESC, title
```

Comment: использовал CTE и окошки, должно работать

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]